# post facebook data

Tags: android, facebook

I am having a listView in which when i click on the list view the whole data present in the list view's particular row  should be posted in the specific format in which it is present in that row.
(I am using a custom Adapter which has a image, 2 text views)
Can anyone suggest me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can we done using image.If you get(any how) the image of that row
  then it can be posted on facebook(in the form of image but not text) in same format as
  its being displayed in that row .

Comment: yes just thought the same and started working to do that.
Do you have any idea to proceed in that way?

Comment: Can you help me in getting the layout's height and width dynamically?
I tried using it but i am getting 0 ,0 as result.